# Login with facebook and then register a username

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, authentication

I'm quite confused trying to create a login with facebook in my iOS app which then will ask the user to create an username and password to complete his first login.

I have integrated the facebook login succesfully, but after the facebook login I want my users to register as users with their own usernames and passwords, which they should use after they have logout from the app.

A good example is Instagram, where the user can login with facebook and thereafter create own username and password. Their usernames should be their userID.

Is there anyone who can help me with a code for that?

I would really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: You will need to build some sort of web service using something along the lines of Ruby on Rails or PHP. From there you can send a POST or GET request to the web service which can then store this information in a database of some sort (i'd personally use PHP and MySQL). You can also create other services to provide authentication or whatever your app requires.

Comment: During login you can get the Assess id of the user then using that id you can get the FB username and you can redirect them to the signup view of your app..  I dont know what is the exact issue you are facing..

Comment: Hey people, sorry haven't been in here since june! You can see what we're working on right here: clokteam.tumblr.com or facebook.com/clokapp - thanks.

Comment: this is exactly what we'd like to implement. Is it still possible? How does it work?